# Inconsistent squeaking

Tags: noise, hyundai, intermittent-problems, elantra, squeaking

I have a 2015 Hyundai Elantra. Just today I noticed an inconsistent squeaking coming from the front of the car.  Here are some things I've noticed so far:

- It sometimes happens when just driving and goes away when tapping the brakes.
- There is no squeaking when driving, but will sometimes squeek when tapping the brakes.
- It sometimes squeaks when turning the steering wheel to the right.
- It does not appear to be speed dependent.  The squeaking doesn't get higher pitched when going faster, or lower pitched when going slower. It does not squeak when not moving.

I am bringing the car in tomorrow to be checked, but I am curious what people think, to see if it matches what the mechanic says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got a text from the mechanic, apparently it is the brake squeal tabs.

I have never heard of these before, but after quick googling, they are real.  I'm surprised the sound isn't consistent though.  If a pad is so low that the tab is pressing up against the rotor causing squeal, why would it be so inconsistent?  Well, I am heading to the mechanic to talk to them.

Comment: The devices are not precision items - so some inconsistency seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a bad wheel bearing. Easy to check. Just jack the front of the car up getting the front tire completely off the ground and shake/rock it ( top to bottom not side to side) If it has play in it its a good chance its going or already gone bad. Also if the tread on the tire is more substantially worn than the other side than thats another indication of a wheel bearing going/gone bad